# HQL query to get one value, with distinct? grouping by?

Tags: sql, hql

Im trying to get just one for every c_id. I have the following data:

```
+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| c_id    | country | birth_date | bank_account        | state_of_bank_acc | ddate      | 
+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| b_111   | FRA     | 1991-06-01 | FR99111111111111111 | active            | 2022-06-03 |
| b_111   | FRA     | 1991-06-01 | FR92222222222222222 | active            | 2022-06-03 |
| b_111   | FRA     | 1991-06-01 | FR99333333333333333 | active            | 2022-06-03 |
| c_999   | DEU     | 1987-01-25 | DEU777777777777777  | inactive          | 2022-06-03 |
| c_999   | DEU     | 1987-01-25 | DEU888888888888888  | active            | 2022-06-03 |
| n_777   | DEU     | 1987-01-25 | DEU888888888888888  | active            | 2022-06-03 |
+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
```

How can I do it to get just one for every c_id as you can see in the following data:

```
+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| c_id    | country | birth_date | bank_account        | state_of_bank_acc | ddate      | 
+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
| b_111   | FRA     | 1991-06-01 | FR99111111111111111 | active            | 2022-06-03 |
| c_999   | DEU     | 1987-01-25 | DEU777777777777777  | inactive          | 2022-06-03 |
| n_777   | DEU     | 1987-01-25 | DEU888888888888888  | active            | 2022-06-03 |
+---------+---------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Comment: On what condition to keep that one record for each c_id? distinct can make 777 and 999 unique but there are 3 bank_account for 111, which one you want to keep?

Comment: Hi @Hana Don't care what bank_account keep but just one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about c_id unique, just use below:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY bank_account DESC) RNK
    FROM test_tbl
) T
WHERE T.RNK = 1
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nAqwQCv7Zc1JxPd4g6hvFj/0)

Comment: Thanks for the help Hana, but this is not working for me :( I reduced the rows but i keep one with 2 values. When i check the rank, two of these rows are with rank 1 and another 1 with rank 3. So I get 2 rows with rnk 1

Comment: You can add more columns .e.g. ddate... into ORDER BY to make it unique